# Maven not including sqlite-jdbc

Tags: java, sqlite, maven

It seems like maven is not adding `sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar` automatically to my
project. Im pretty new to Java, so im not sure what I did wrong.

### Minimal example

From the [Maven in 5
minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html),
create a project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

In the new project, add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.36.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

To the dependencies, they will look like this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.36.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And edit `src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java` to look like this:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // We make sure that we have the driver
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }

        Connection con = null;

        try {
            String connection_string = "jdbc:sqlite:test.db";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string);

            System.out.println("It works");
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (final SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
mvn package
```

And finally run the project with:

```
java -cp ./target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

And I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

But if I manually add `sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar`, it works correctly.

```
java -cp ".\target\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pabsa\.m2\repository\org\xerial\sqlite-jdbc\3.36.0.3\sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar" com.mycompany.app.App
```

What did I did wrong, or why is Maven not adding it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior from Maven: the jar of the application does not include its dependencies by default. Two options:

1. Either execute the main class using the [`maven-exec-plugin`](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-main-method):

   ```
   mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"
   ```
2. Or create a [jar with its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) and execute it instead of the regular jar.